# Is it possible to decompress data using GZIP, after some garbage-bytes are added to the end of compressed data byte array?

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

This is just an example in c# how i mean to add garbage-data to the end, please consider it as a pseudo-code:

```
[Test]
public void TestGzipCompressor_WhenCompressCalledWithAddedExtraDataToTheEnd_ShouldReturnValidData()
{
    var extraBytesToAddToTheEnd = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    
    //creating a test-byte array
    var bytesToPopulateArrayWith= new byte[9] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    var byteList = new List<byte> { };
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        inputBytes.AddRange(bytesToPopulateArrayWith);
    }
    
    //Getting data as a compressed byte list
    List<byte> compressedBytes = GzipCompressor.Compress(byteList);

    //adding extra garbage-bytes to the end of the compressed data byte-array
    compressedBytes.AddRange(extraBytesToAddToTheEnd);

    //Getting original data after decompression
    byte[] decompressedBytes = GzipCompressor.Decompress(compressedBytes.ToArray());

    decompressedBytes.Should().BeEquivalentTo(stringBytes);
}
```

It works perfectly if we add less than 5 bytes:

```
var extraBytesToAddToTheEnd = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

but adding 5 and more bytes to the end throws an "*The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method*" error.

```
var extraBytesToAddToTheEnd = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Compressor implementation is the following:

```
public static class GzipCompressor
    {
        [NotNull]
        public static byte[] Compress([NotNull] byte[] bytes)
        {
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            gzipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            gzipStream.Flush();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        [NotNull]
        public static byte[] Decompress([NotNull] byte[] bytes)
        {
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using var gzipStream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(bytes), CompressionMode.Decompress);
            gzipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            gzipStream.Flush();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

**Does GZIP makes possible to decompress compressed data with some garbage bytes at the end?**
Why does it working with 4 bytes and less, but no more? Is there something wrong with my implementation?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case here, why do you need to do this? If you need to encode data at the end of a very specific file format, why not add the data, add a size at the end, when you go to decompress, read the size at the end, remove the data, then uncompressed. As to why you can get away with 4 bytes, well who knows, you would have to read the RFC, it could be for a lot of reason, like padding, also this might actually fail with other implantations...

Comment: You should read the spec. If you want to add in your own data, you could read the spec on how to do that, specifically section `2.3.1.1`: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952#page-8

Answer (score 2):

Without diving deep into the GZipStream implementation I would guess that it is reading your appended data and trying to interpret it as a gzip frame header and when it gets unexpected input it throws an exception.

The gzip file format is detailed in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952). It consists of a series of frames (called 'members' in the RFC) that all follow a specific format. Each frame has a header block with some optional parts, followed by the DEFLATE-compressed data and an 8-byte footer. The format supports optional 'extra data' chunks in the header but most implementations seem to ignore them.

The file format does not however allow arbitrary data to be appended or prepended to the file. By appending data to the gzip stream you're changing it to something that *is not* a gzip file. You've created a gzip variant that won't work for a compliant implementation and has undefined behavior on non-compliant implementations.

Depending on your needs there are other compression formats that may be better suited. If it's for internal use then you might want to create your own format that encapsulates the gzip or deflate data. If you absolutely have to produce a gzip file then you'll need to locate a library that allows you to read/write extra data in the gzip header.

(Wish I could tag people - [Mark Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler) is the definitive source on this stuff on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in `GzipStream`. It is not recognizing junk until after four bytes of it. As Corey noted, anything after a gzip member that is not another complete gzip member signifies an invalid gzip stream. The class should recognize that whether there is five, four, or one bytes of junk.

If you want to stop decompressing after one gzip member, you can instead use `DeflateStream` to decode the compressed data that is inside the gzip member. Then you will just need to decode the gzip header and trailer yourself, and compute the CRC on the decompressed data to compare with the CRC in trailer. See [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).